# Swift 3 - Reading array and dictionary from JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, macos, dictionary

I don't know how to access this nested array/dictionary values in my result. I tried many variations, possibly only a part was wrong but i didn't get the values. Here is my result and I want to get the values of the subarticles array. Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Comment: Please show the code that you have try.

Comment: Not sure how basic you are going but:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105